# Import soundfile as sf but on jupyter notebook sf gives NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-import, nameerror

I installed Soundfile by pip install soundfile.
Here is my code:

```
import soundfile as sf
def speech_file_to_array_fn(batch):
    speech_array, sampling_rate = sf.read(batch["file"])
    batch["speech"] = speech_array
    batch["sampling_rate"] = sampling_rate
    batch["target_text"] = batch["text"]
    return batch

timit = timit.map(speech_file_to_array_fn, remove_columns=timit.column_names["train"], num_proc=4)
```

but it gives an NameError. **NameError: name 'sf' is not defined**

I could not see the problem, I work on jupyter notebook.

Comment: Does `import soundfile` work?

Comment: No, unfortunately

Comment: Ok! That means that `soundfile` hasn't been installed correctly. Depending on the system, sometimes it's an issue with Python 3. Try `sudo pip3 install soundfile`

Comment: I work on windows so I used pip3 install soundfile.

Comment: Does that work?

Comment: No actually. I unistalled and installed again and again but nothing changes

Comment: Right. Try `pip3 install SoundFile` with capital letters.

Comment: It says the requirement already satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to version 0.10.2 solved to issue for me (pip install SoundFile==0.10.2).